# Calling promise-returning function within promise-returning function

Tags: node.js, promise

I am rather new to JavaScript and never really worked with promises before. My code works but I would like to learn if there is a better approach?

I want to implement the following functionality:

- Query DB to check if user is in a team
- if yes, query DB for items belonging to that team

Both functions return promises.

Thanks a lot.

````js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var _ = require("underscore");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "ap-southeast-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8042",
});

var dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var userID = "user123";
var teamID = "team456";


function checkUserIsTeamMember(teamID, userID) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // get team
    let params = {
      TableName: "someTable",
      ScanIndexForward: true,
      KeyConditionExpression: "#PK = :PK And begins_with(#SK, :SK)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":PK": "T#" + teamID,
        ":SK": "U#" + userID,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#PK": "PK",
        "#SK": "SK",
      },
    };
    dynamoDb
      .query(params)
      .promise()
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.Count > 0) {
          resolve("User is team member.");
        } else {
          reject("User is not team member.");
        }
      });
  });
}

function getItems(teamID) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let params = {
      TableName: "someTable",
      ScanIndexForward: true,
      IndexName: "GSI2",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#PK = :PK And begins_with(#SK, :SK)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":PK": "T#" + teamID,
        ":SK": "I#",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#PK": "GSI2PK",
        "#SK": "GSI2SK",
      },
    };

    // check first
    checkUserIsTeamMember(teamID, userID)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        
        // resolve another promise
        resolve(dynamoDb.query(params).promise());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        // return empty list if user is not authorized (not team member)
        // not sure if resolving this in the catch block is correct

        resolve([]);
      });
  });
}

getItems(teamID).then((data) => {
  console.log(data.Items);
});

```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. It helps us give a better review when the title indicates what the code does.